# query string of tid not working on page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I need my view to default the exposed filter depending on the ?tid= variable that i put in the url .  It was working before, but now it no longer does.  Is there a setting in the view that makes that tid variable work?

Comment: Are you using contextual filters. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view you need an exposed filter on the term field. In the settings for this field, expand on the "More" section near the bottom and you'll see a field called "filter identifier" - enter tid in this field (in this screenshot, you can see I used "category" it can be whatever label you want to give it). Click Apply this display. Save the view.

[image]